# Why don't need to specify variable in the constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I am learning javascript, in the constructor there isn't a var declaration there, just get and set method there. Could anyone tell me why? I think there should be a statement like var name; in the constructor?

```
<script>
function Person(name){
    this.getName=function(){
        return name;
    };

    this.setName=function(value){
        name=value;
    };
}
</script>
```

why don't put

```
var name
```

in the constructor?

Comment: As per deathApril's answer, you should consider reading up on function scoping https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Person(name){
    this.getName=function(){
        return name;
    };

    this.setName=function(value){
        name=value;
    };
}
```

because name is already scoped to Person function since it's an argument of Person

you dont need (and shouldnt) write `var name`.

Answer (score 1):

because function arguments are already in scope and you don't want to override the argument by `undefined`?

see [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope#answer-500459) to learn more about scope

Answer (score 0):

setName method is implemented in case you want to change the name of an existing object.
e.g:

```
function Person(name){
    this.getName=function(){
        return name;
    };

    this.setName=function(value){
        name=value;
    };
}

var tom = new Person("tom");
var harry = new Person("harry");
```

So If you want tom to have new name you must call

```
tom.setName("Dick");
```

After this

```
tom.getName();
```

Will return "Dick".

Best regards.